# Right place to put a 'global' data structure

Tags: objective-c

**Context:**
I'm generalizing some aspects of the iOS project I've just inherited. One of the things I want is a data structure accessible from anywhere in the application where user controls can access app-specific style information (`UIColor` definitions etc.).

**Question:** If I've defined a data structure containing data which needs to be 'globally' accessible, where is considered the right place to instantiate this object and what is the right way for other objects to obtain a reference to it? A bit of research turns up the following options:

- Create the data structure as a property of my `AppDelegate`; initialise it on `applicationDidFinishLaunching`; access it via `((myAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).getStyleDefs`.
- Make the structure a global singleton (either lazily loaded or eagerly with instantiation from the `AppDelegate`).

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt Gallagher's article on [Singletons, AppDelegates and top-level data](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) is a great reference on the pros and cons of various ways of handling this in Objective C. The very short summary is: Use a singleton.

The main arguments used against singletons in other places fall roughly into two camps:

1. *You are doing it wrong in the first place if you need this kind of a global object.* This is often good advice but it seems like you have already decided to go this route. Note that the app delegate pattern is just hijacking a singleton Cocoa automatically creates for you and hanging more stuff on it. So its not really a break from singletons.
2. *Singletons should not be true singletons in the sense that is meant in other languages.* A traditional singleton actually enforces the prohibition that only one can ever be instantiated in your application. In Objective C we mostly use singletons where there is a default object created for you by a class method, but you can create more if you want to. Apple's classes use this fairly commonly. In cases where it is expected that you won't created more the class method starts with `default*` and in cases where you might it starts with `shared*`.

Note to instantiate your singleton the best modern approach is to use Grand Central Dispatch such as described in this [note on Objective C singletons](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/a-note-on-objective-c-singletons.html).

Comment: Aye, I'd read exactly the same article and he makes an excellent case. Trouble is, I've also read a few (very passionate!) articles and blogs which completely demonize the global singleton as a concept! Seems like the Objective-C community isn't as against them as some other people!.. Thanks for your input here :)

Comment: Singletons are useful in certain cases, and Cocoa uses them quite a bit (e.g. NSUserDefaults).

Comment: @sjwarner I added some more details in my answer about my take on the pros and cons of the singleton debate.

Comment: Excellent Cocoa-specific stuff there @torrey.lyons, cheers. Looks like the best way to go in order to stay in line with the current conventional wisdom is to use a pseudo-singleton, so that's what I'll do. I like the simplification provided by GCD too, but unfortunately I still need to support iOS3 so looks like I'll be going [the long way round](https://gist.github.com/659709)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a separate file called `SharedConstants(.h/.m)` and have all the application wide constants available in there.

Put something like

`#define sharedColor [UIColor colorWithRed...]`

in the `.m` version of the file and then you'll be able to use it in any other class that includes the `SharedConstants.h` file.